# Semi Gauss integral limit

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

I am courrently stuck at showing that: $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\int_0^xe^{t^2-x^2}dt=0$. Non of my tries by estimations lead to succes so I would appriciate any kind of help.

Comment: your integral is given by $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } e^{-x^2} \text{erfi}(x)$

Comment: I know that fact but i am looking for an elementary argument since i only need the limit value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon\gt0$ and, for every $x\geqslant\varepsilon$, cut the integral into two parts at $x-\varepsilon$, then the integrand is increasing and at most $1$ everywhere and $2\varepsilon x-\varepsilon^2\geqslant\varepsilon x$ hence the integral $I(x)$ is such that $$I(x)\leqslant\varepsilon+\int_0^{x-\varepsilon}\mathrm e^{t^2-x^2}\mathrm dt\leqslant\varepsilon+x\,\mathrm e^{(x-\varepsilon)^2-x^2}=\varepsilon+x\,\mathrm e^{-2\varepsilon x+\varepsilon^2}\leqslant\varepsilon+x\,\mathrm e^{-\varepsilon x}.$$ When $x\to\infty$, $x\ll\mathrm e^{\varepsilon x}$ hence $$\limsup_{x\to\infty}\,I(x)\leqslant\varepsilon.$$ This holds for every $\varepsilon\gt0$ and $I(x)\gt0$ for every $x$ hence $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}I(x)=0.$$

Comment: I was trying similar argument since yasterday evening and can't believe i couldend finish that ;D, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite $$I=\int e^{t^2-x^2}dt=e^{-x^2}\int e^{t^2}dt$$ Now, change variable $t=iz$ to get $$\int e^{t^2}dt=i \int e^{-z^2}dz=\frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}(z)=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}(t)$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: "I am sure that you can take from here." Sorry but I cannot, unless you point me to some specific property of erfi which would make the result direct.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[Exp[t%5E2-x%5E2]%2C%7Bt%2C0%2Cx%7D]), I obtained:

$$\int_0^x e^{t^2-x^2}dt = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi} e^{-x^2} \text{erfi}(x)$$

with erfi$(x)$ being the [imaginary error function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Erfi[x]). Using L'Hôpital's rule it can be shown with $\frac{d}{dx}\text{erfi}(x) = \frac{2 e^{x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$that
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\text{erfi}(x)}{e^{x^2}} = 0 .$$

Comment: If the goal is to use L'Hôpital, the *détour* by erfi is useless (as witnessed by the successive appearances of $\sqrt{\pi}/2$ and $2/\sqrt{\pi}$).